# Why is a Martingale defined as a discrete process where the conditional expected value of the next observation is equal to the previous?

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-expectation, martingales

In my notes, I am seeing that a Martingale is defined as

> A discrete time stochastic process where the conditional expected value of the next observation, given all past observations, is equal to the most recent observation.

or mathematically

$$
E[Z_{n+1}|Z_n = z_n, \ldots, Z_1 = z_1] = z_n
$$

where $Z_n$ is a Martingale.

I am wondering why the statement is not more general because we can show that

$$
E[Z_n] = E[Z_{n - 1}] = \ldots = E[Z_1]
$$

Instead of a *conditional* expectation, we simply have that the unconditional expectation is equal to the previous expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two properties:
$$
A:\qquad E[Z_{n+1}|Z_n = z_n, \ldots, Z_1 = z_1] = z_n
$$
and
$$
B:\qquad E[Z_n] = E[Z_{n - 1}] = \ldots = E[Z_1]
$$
Then $A$ implies $B$, but $B$ does not imply $A$.  So, $B$ is a property of martingales; but $A$ is much a more powerful condition.

Comment: When you say B is a property of martingales, are you implying that A isn't? I thought A is fundamental property of martingales?

Comment: $A$ is the definition of martingales.  All martingales have property $B$, but some non-martingales also have property $B$.

Comment: Ah I see. Is condition A frequently written as $$
E[Z_{n+1} | Z_n, Z_{n-1}, \ldots, Z_1] = Z_n
$$, i.e., the expectation here is a random variable? I feel that I see this representation more often.

Comment: @David Yes. Conditional expectations are random variables.